# How can I double variable within method in rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, double

How can I double `@user` var, if I do not double it, the test will throw error of

> call update_attributes of nil:NilClass

```
class TestController
   def foo!
      @user = current_user
      @user.update_attribute(user_params)
   end
end

RSpec.describe TestController, type: :controller do
    describe "#foo" do
        it "should be passed" do
            @specific_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            allow_any_instance_of(TestController).to receive(:foo!).and_return(true)
            allow_any_instance_of(TestController).to receive(@user).and_return(@specific_user)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your test is that it doesn't test anything. The controller test should make a request to test the method `get :foo!`

About stubbing, in your case `current_user` method can be stubbed instead:

```
RSpec.describe TestController, type: :controller do
  describe "#foo" do
    it "should be passed" do
      @specific_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      allow(controller).to receive(:foo!).and_return(true)
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(@specific_user)
    end
  end
end
```

And yeah, in the controller test the controller instance can be accessed by calling `controller` method.

What also allows to set an instance variable in this controller:

```
RSpec.describe TestController, type: :controller do
  describe "#foo" do
    it "should be passed" do
      @specific_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      allow(controller).to receive(:foo!).and_return(true)
      controller.instance_variable_set(:@user, @specific_user)
    end
  end
end
```